# Chinese characters in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a VBA Module that reads file names from several server folders (about 1.5 million records) and places these filenames into several worksheets. Many of these filenames contain chinese characters and when the filenames are written to the worksheets Excel is substituting those characters with question marks. That character substitution prevents the next step happening (an upload to Salesforce of the files and filenames). Is there some way of preserving the chinese characters when the filename is written to the worksheet?

I'm in a commercial situation using Excel 365 and I won't be able to change any Office settings 'behind the scenes'.

Comment: Can you provide the relevant code?

Comment: You may need to install support for the alphabet, or a language pack with the proper fonts.

Comment: Hope you have solved it by now. You need to set the system locale to Chinese. Excel is not Unicode compliant. Setting system locale is Window's way of making Unicode-non-compliant software to support Unicode. By doing so, I can have variables' and sub's names in Chinese.